# ¿Cómo registro los datos del while?

Tags: r, lista, while

M piden realizar un menú, que al presionar 1, le pida digitar la cantidad de números que desee comparar, y posteriormente pedir una por una las n opciones y así enviar el numero máximo del conjunto de datos, lo que no se es como hacer que se acumulen en la lista números todos los datos que se van anotando

```
 menu <- select.list(
 title = "Este es mi menu",
choices = c("Ejercicio 1","Ejercicio 2","Salir")
)

if (menu == "Ejercicio 1"){

num=as.numeric(readline("Digite la cantidad de números que desea comparar: "))

if (num == 1){

uno <- as.numeric(readline("Digite dato a comparar: "))
print(paste("El número mayor es:", uno)) 
}

while (num > 1){
  
  numeros<- (as.numeric(readline("Digite el dato a comparar: ")))
  
  numeros<- c(numeros)
  
  cantidad <- length(numeros)
  cantidad

  
  if(num == cantidad){
 
 break    
   max<- max(c(numeros:n))
   
   print(paste("El número mayor es:", max)) 
 
   }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas "acumular" cada ingreso en un vector:

```
numeros <- numeric()
while (num > 1) {
  numero_ingresado <- as.numeric(readline("Digite el dato a comparar: "))
  numeros <- c(numeros, numero_ingresado))
```

Creamos una variable fuera del while:  `numeros <- numeric()` y dentro del primero, acumulamos `numeros <- c(numeros, numero_ingresado))`.

Adicionalmente te hago una sugerencia, en ciclos dónde conocemos el total de iteraciones, es más simple si se implementa mediante un `for`:

```
numeros <- numeric()
for (i in 1:num) {
  numero_ingresado <- as.numeric(readline("Digite el dato a comparar: "))
  numeros <- c(numeros, numero_ingresado)
}

max <- max(numeros)
print(paste("El número mayor es:", max))
```